# Cauchy sequence but not convergent

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have this space $E=\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ and the inner product $d(f,g)=\int_0^1 |f(x)-g(x)|\,{\rm d}x$.

Who have an idea about a simple sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ which is Cauchy but not convergent in $(E,d)$?

Comment: @ZacharySelk Thanks for pointing that out, I deleted the answer. I mixed up the norms.

Comment: @Kibble If we were talking about uniform convergence, you would be 100% correct. However when you see integral signs you should think that individual points don't matter. If I was a bit groggier, I might have posted the same answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: consider a sequence of functions like:

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 0 \text{ for } x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}]\\
\text{linear} \text{ for } x\in [\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{2}+\frac1n]\\
1 \text{ for } x\in [\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n},1]
\end{cases}$$

Comment: i choose: $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 0 \text{ for } x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}]\\n(x-\frac12) \text{ for } x\in [\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{2}+\frac1n]\\
1 \text{ for } x\in [\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n},1]
\end{cases}$$ it is cauchy and i found that it's limite $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0, x\in [0,\frac12]\\1, x\in ]\frac12,1]\end{cases}$$ how to prove that f is not continuous please

Answer (score 1):

Take $f= 1_{[1/2,1]}$. Approximate it by $f_n$ which agrees with $f$ outside of $[1/2-1/n,1/2+1/n]$ and interpolates linearly inbetween. By dominated convergence $f_n \to f \in L^1([0,1])$ and hence $f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in the $d$-metric. Now let $g \in \mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ and assume for contradiction that $d(f_n,g) \to 0$. Since $g \in L^1$ and limits in $L^1$ are unique, we find $g=f$ almost everywhere. Since $f,g$ are both right continuous we find $g=f$, and thus $g \notin \mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, a contradiction.